# Tkinter Label Background

Tags: python, tkinter, background, label

I am trying to make label have transparent background but I can't figure it out. Help me please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeeB5.png)

Here is my sample code:

```
    IMAGE_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\tk_project\\StartPageBG\\home.png'
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 450

    # Add image file 
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(IMAGE_PATH).resize((WIDTH, HEIGHT),))
    lbl = tk.Label(self, image=img)
    lbl.img = img  # Keep a reference in case this code put is in a function.
    lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center') 

    

    #for time-in button----------------------------------------
    admintimebtn = ttk.Button(self, text ="Time-In",
    command = open_popup)
    admintimebtn.place(x=550, y=100) #ito pang pwesto ng button

    #for new button----------------------------------------
    newbtn = ttk.Button(self, text ="New ID",
    command = lambda : controller.show_frame(New))
    newbtn.place(x=550, y=150) #ito pang pwesto ng button

    #for records button----------------------------------------
    recordsbtn = ttk.Button(self, text ="Records",
    command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Records))
    recordsbtn.place(x=650, y=150) #ito pang pwesto ng button

    
    

    def sec():
        time_string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %p \n %A \n %x') # time format 
        l1.config(text=time_string)
        l1.after(1000, sec)# time delay of 1000 milliseconds

        if strftime("%p") == "AM" and strftime("%H") != "12":
            greetings = ttk.Label(self,font=('Anton',40,'bold',),text="GOOD MORNING!", foreground="white")
            greetings.place(x=30, y=350)
        elif strftime("%p") == "PM" and strftime("%H") < "18":
            greetings = ttk.Label(self,font=('Anton',40,'bold',),text="GOOD AFTERNOON!", foreground="white")
            greetings.place(x=30, y=350)
        elif strftime("%p") == "PM" and strftime("%H") > "17":
            greetings = ttk.Label(self,font=('Anton',40,'bold',),text="GOOD EVENING!", foreground="white")
            greetings.place(x=30, y=350)
        else:
            greetings = ttk.Label(self,font=('Anton',40,'bold',),text="GOOD EVENING!", foreground="white")
            greetings.place(x=30, y=350)


    l1=Label(self,font=('Anton',20,'bold',), foreground="white")
    l1.place(x=30,y=250)
    
    sec()
```

Comment: tkinter widgets do not support transparent background.  However you can use the `Canvas` widget to show the image, text and other widgets, then you can have transparent text but *other widgets* are still not transparent.